# fail2ban refuses to work on Raspberrypi Zero 2 W

Tags: fail2ban

I have a RaspberryPi Zero 2 W. I installed fail2ban using the command `sudo apt install fail2ban -y`. I have been referring to the following resources: [PiMyLifeUp](https://pimylifeup.com/raspberry-pi-fail2ban/), [HowtoGeek](https://www.howtogeek.com/675010/how-to-secure-your-linux-computer-with-fail2ban/) as well as [LinuxSize](https://linuxize.com/post/install-configure-fail2ban-on-ubuntu-20-04/).

No matter what setting I do in `/etc/fail2ban/jail.local`, I always get the following error:

```
× fail2ban.service - Fail2Ban Service
Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/fail2ban.service; enabled; preset: enabled)
Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2024-02-18 22:08:00 GMT; 6min ago
Duration: 711ms
Docs: man:fail2ban(1)
Process: 23922 ExecStart=/usr/bin/fail2ban-server -xf start (code=exited, status=255/EXCEPTION)
Main PID: 23922 (code=exited, status=255/EXCEPTION)
CPU: 699ms
```

when I run the command: `sudo systemctl status fail2ban.service`.

Any suggestions on what to do? I have tried to look at resources on GitHub, [particularly this one](https://github.com/fail2ban/fail2ban/issues/3292). Other resources I have tried to look at are: [Resource1](https://github.com/fail2ban/fail2ban/issues/1937), [Resource 2](https://github.com/fail2ban/fail2ban/blob/master/config/paths-debian.conf), [GitHub Comment](https://github.com/fail2ban/fail2ban/issues/3292#issuecomment-1142503461), and [This GitHub issue](https://github.com/fail2ban/fail2ban/issues/3567).

I am **not** a programmer by any stretch of imagination. I am a novice. I am not sure if my `.conf` file is incorrectly set, or if I have to make any other changes. Most resources available online seem to be old as the file contents are different from what I see installed in my system.

**Edit 1:** The system is currently running Debian 6.1.76-1 (2024-02-01) armv6l. The fail2ban installed is verion 1.0.2-2.

Comment: Welcome! Not sure how to put it, so I'll be blunt: stackoverflow is about **developing** software, not about using and managing it. A better place to ask (and one you will more likely find a solution to your problem) is https://serverfault.com a different site of the larger StackExchange network.

Comment: Also, I highly recommend reading an essay called "How to ask questions the smart way" by Eric S Raymond to all novices. Do not take this the wrong way: It contains *valuable* insights and practical tipps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be an unresolved problem with fail2ban in Debian. There is a bug report of it [here](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=770171).

Basically, There is a bug with the Debian implementation of fail2ban, where the debian backend is now all systemd but fail2ban expects the old way for logging. Here's how you fix it.

First, activate systemd as the backend by going to the `defaults-debian.conf` using the command: `sudo nano /etc/fail2ban/defaults-debian.conf`

and adding `backend = systemd` under the `[DEFAULTS]` tag in the file. So it looks like:

```
 [DEFAULT]
   backend = systemd
```

Next, go to `/etc/fail2ban/filter.d/sshd.conf` and find the line: `journalmatch = _SYSTEMD_UNIT=ssh.service + _COMM=sshd`

add the word `[Init]` above it. So now it should look as:

```
[Init]
   journalmatch = _SYSTEMD_UNIT=ssh.service + _COMM=sshd
```

Done.

Now restart the service with: `sudo systemctl restart fail2ban`, and then check with `sudo systemctl status fail2ban`.

P.S: The link to the debian bug report was given to me by the kind folks over at [reddit](https://redd.it/1awfi1e) in the Debian subreddit.